# Translate host path to docker container inner path

Tags: bash, docker

I need to know at least one path with which a running docker container can access a file located on the host. From the host, I know the path of the file for the host, but not in the container.
The solution must be valid for each file mapped into the container and should fail if the given file is not mounted inside it.

**For example**:
A docker container is ran with the option `-v /srv:/etc`.
On the host, there is a file `/srv/foo`.
From inside the container, this file is known as `/etc/foo`.

From the host, how can I predict that `/srv/foo` will turn into `/etc/foo` inside the container?
*(yes, I really need to do that...)*

---

I came up with this tiny ugly script and I'm hopping to find a proper solution. I already know `for` loop sucks but my question here is about the idea.

```
 containerid="123abc"
 hostpath="/srv/foo" 
 dockerpath="" # <-- How to set that?

 # -- For all mapped directories (host side)
 for hostdir in $(docker inspect --format '{{ range .Mounts }}{{ .Source }} {{ end }}' ${containerid}); do

    # -- If hostpath is inside hostdir (considering symlinks...)
    case $(readlink -f ${hostpath})/ in $(readlink -f ${hostdir})/*)

        # -- Obtain the location inside the container for hostdir
        dockerdir=$(docker inspect --format "{{ range .Mounts }}{{ if eq .Source \"${hostdir}\" }}{{ .Destination }}{{ end }}{{ end }}" ${containerid})

        # -- Deduce the path into the container
        realhpath=$(readlink -f $hostpath)
        hpathsubstraction=${realhpath#$hostdir}
        dockerpath="${dockerdir}/${hpathsubstraction}"

        # -- Break the case and the "mapped directories" for-loop
        break 1
    esac
  done

  # Here if $dockerpath is empty, then $hostpath can not be seen inside $containerid.
```